# Is there a way to force exception message to be English for Java 1.7

Tags: java, jvm, locale, multilingual

I've almost tried everything including:

1. Change system region and language to be 'english US'
2. Use Locale.setDefaultLocale()
3. Pass in JVM arguments

It prints out:

```
Default locale is : en_US
```

BUT my application is still throwing exception with Chinese exception message

Does this have anything to do with Spring? (my app is based on Spring, but there is no locale-related config whatsover, so it should be just using whatever is default)

Can anyone help me with this?

UPDATE:

I'm basically getting a `java.io.IOException` with Chinese message equivalent to

> An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

changing the locale didn't seem to affect this, maybe this is indeed an OS level thing?

Comment: Where is the exception coming from?  Is it using a message given to it by the OS?  If so you need to change the language at the OS level.

Comment: How strange. What sort of exception? Is it from some Chinese library? Did you download a Chinese Java?

Comment: thanks guys, this is what I see from the exception:

java.io.IOException: {chinese message here}

The chinese message is equivalent to " An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host". I wonder if this is OS level thing, like what Peter said...

Comment: are you able to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

"An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host" is a standard error message [from the Windows Sockets library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668.aspx) (code 10054).

In retrieving the error message for the error code, the specification of the [FormatMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679351.aspx) function says it will take the user or system locale into account. As far as I know, setting the system region and language to English US should do that. Perhaps a Chinese version of Windows just doesn't have English language messages available?

Answer (score 0):

[Throwable.getLocalizedMessage()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getLocalizedMessage%28%29) might work, assuming that the library you're using provides localized exception messages.

Comment: I don't want localized messages though, I just want to get the original English exception message

Comment: Ah. I thought that the library was written in Chinese and you were getting the default exception messages.

Comment: no worries, I updated the original question, hopefully it provides more info now